# Postgres schema access changes before and after pg_dump

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy, pg-dump, pgbouncer

I have a Postgres database defined with the `public` schema and it is accessed from within a Python application.  Before doing a `pg_dump`, the tables can be accessed without using a qualified table name, for example `select * from user` works.  After doing the `pg_dump`, `select * from user` fails with a `relation "user" does not exist` error, but `select * from public.user` works.  No restore has been performed.

Since this is within an application, I cannot change the access to include the schema.  The application uses `sqlalchemy` and `pgbouncer` for interacting with the database.

In trying to figure out what's happening, I've discovered that running `pg_dump` causes the session to change.  Before running the command, by querying `pg_stat_activity`, I can see there are 10 sessions in the pool, one active and nine idle.  After running the command, a different session is active and the other nine are idle.  Also, the settings in `pg_db_role_setting` and `pg_user` look correct for the session that I can see.  But, even when those look correct, the query `select * from user` fails.

Also, just for reference, the code currently does not contain `pg_dump` and runs fine.  As soon as I add the `pg_dump`, I see the issues mentioned.

Is there anything in `pg_dump` that could be causing what I'm seeing or is it just a result of going to another session?  Since these are some of the first commands being run after running migrations, is there any reason the sessions should have different settings?  What else am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: 1) There is a `public` schema defined in  the database, no the other way around. 2) Best guess is the [search_path](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/ddl-schemas.html#DDL-SCHEMAS-PATH) has been changed. In `psql` do `show search_path ;` . Also `select name, setting, source, sourcefile from pg_settings where name = 'search_path';` to find what is setting it.

Comment: Hi Adrian, thanks for the helpful suggestion.  I had been logging the output of similar queries, but not `show search_path;`.  Luckily for me, the first run with that showed it changed from the default before the `pg_dump` call to an empty string after the call.  However, rerunning the job showed the default value both before and after the `pg_dump` call, confirming the randomness of the issue.

Comment: Thanks to the Stack Overflow "related" questions I saw a link to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64066007/after-using-pg-dump-behind-pg-bouncer-the-search-path-appears-to-be-altered-and), which is exactly what I needed.   In all my searching before I posted, I didn't see that question, so sorry for the duplicate.